# How to solve offset related error in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to solve this error:

```
Assets/TK2DROOT/tk2d/Code/Sprites/tk2dBaseSprite.cs(594,55): error CS1061: Type 'UnityEngine.BoxCollider2D' does not contain a definition for 'offset' and no extension method 'offset' of type 'UnityEngine.BoxCollider2D' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Code:

```
boxCollider2D.offset = new Vector2(sprite.colliderVertices[0].x * _scale.x, sprite.colliderVertices[0].y * _scale.y);
```

Comment: Have you included the proper libraries?

Comment: Are you using the most updated version of Unity?

Comment: Yeah, i have use the latest version of unity which is actually Unity 5.1.0f3 (32-bit). @user3071284

Comment: May be... yes. But i have to check this up right now. Anyways, what libraries name you are talking about? @mituw16

Comment: Check out the patches to see if there's anything that could address this: https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue. Found out the Unity 4 project was opened with Unity 5, and got automatically converted, including source code of third party libraries. After that the project became incompatible with Unity 4.
So if you planning to use Unity 4, you should use BoxCollider2D.center.

Official docs say:

> BoxCollider2D.center removed in version 5.2.1p2
>   BoxCollider2D.center has been deprecated. Use BoxCollider2D.offset instead (UnityUpgradable) -> offset

Don't really know when BoxCollider2D.offset was added though.